# Let S be a parallelogram not parallel to any of the coordinate planes. Area of S?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Let S be a parallelogram not parallel to any of the coordinate planes.

Let $S_1,S_2,S_3$ denote the areas of the projections of S on the three coordinates planes.

Find the area of S in terms of $S_1, S_2, S_3$ ?

Can anyone give me a hint?

Comment: According to http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Parallelepiped.html , the two edge vectors of the parallelogram forming the matrix A, the volume can be found as $$\text{Volume} = \det(A^TA)^{1/2}$$ and recovering the two vectors from the projections is straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

Let the two vectors of two non-parallel sides be $a=(a_1,a_2,a_3)$ and $b=(b_1,b_2,b_3)$. Then the area^2 of the parallelogram is
$$ S^2=| a \times b |^2 = (a_2 b_3-b_2 a_3)^2 + (a_3 b_1-b_3 a_1)^2 + (a_1 b_2-b_1 a_2)^2 $$

Even at this point, it may be obvious what is about to happen, considering the contents of the brackets... now let's look at a projection. Since all three work in the same way, it suffices to consider the projection onto the plane $z=0$. Projecting $a$ and $b$ onto this plane gives
$$ P(a)=(a_1,a_2,0) \text{ and } P(b)=(b_1,b_2,0), $$
and then the area^2 of the parallelogram spanned by $P(a)$ and $P(b)$ is
$$ (S_1)^2 = | P(a) \times P(b) |^2 = 0 + 0 + (a_1 b_2-b_1 a_2)^2 $$

Hence $S^2 = \sum_{i=1}^3 (S_i)^2$. (This will actually generalise to [bivectors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bivector) in any number of dimensions.)